# Taking database snapshots and its impact on performance

Tags: db2

On our db2 system all monitors are set to ON. My question is, does taking snapshots have radical impact on performance? I'm talking about taking snapshot every 10 seconds.

How about db2pd and its impact on performance?

I couldn't find any answer to these questions on the web.

**Edit:**
By snapshot I mean getting information about database (such as number of reads, locks, etc), not copying the actual database data.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Snapshots are heavier because they need to use the engine.

Instead, db2pd does not create any latches, so it is faster. However, sometimes the information is not accurate.

- PIC db2pd - http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.trb.doc/doc/c0054595.html
- Monitor switches - http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.admin.mon.doc%2Fdoc%2Fc0005719.html
- Chris Eaton article - http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/db2luw/monitor-switches-5567
- http://www.zinox.com/node/70

Comment: I need to get information about average latency of IO operations (read/write) of database, index files, logs and most importantly tablespaces. I can't get those information with db2pd. Is it possible to get those information with db2pd?

Answer (score 0):

The traditional snapshot monitor does have a noticeable performance penalty, so it's unwise to keep the monitor switches on all the time, unless you're troubleshooting some issue. The 10 second snapshot frequency also seems excessive.

If you're using DB2 9.7 or later, consider using [event monitors](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.mon.doc/doc/r0005993.html), which are less intrusive in terms of performance.